# Why is pandas.read_sas() so much slower than pandas.read_csv()?

Tags: python, windows, pandas, csv

I'm writing a Python script to do some data work for me and I have a question about performance. I'm running Python 3.6 and the most up-to-date package of pandas. OS is Windows 10. Anyway here's the jist - I'm reading in a SAS table of about 71 million rows and 39 columns in this way:

```
want = []
for chuck in pd.read_sas('my_sas_table.sas7bdat',chunksize = 50000,encoding='cp1252'):
    chuck['DT_COL'] = pd.to_timedelta(chuck['DT_COL'], unit='D') + pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
    want.append(chuck)
```

This is taking about 35-40 minutes to read in the table. If I were to go into SAS, export the table as a CSV and than just do

```
pd.read_csv('my_sas_table.csv')
```

it only takes about 5 minutes. I don't want to do this because this script will be automated - and I'm trying to avoid doing anything outside of Python. Is there a trick I might be missing or can someone explain this crazy difference in performance?

I know changing the date column on the chunks might be slowing down the read a little bit - but I'm just not convinced that it's causing the

```
pd.read_sas()
```

to be 8x slower than

```
pd.read_csv()
```

but I'm no expert and I'm hoping one of you might be!

Thanks!

Comment: From what I have read, read_sas() still has major performance issues due to the way it handles bytes. It may be beneficial to read the sas file like so:
data = pd.read_sas('my_sas_table.sas7bdat',chunksize = 50000,encoding='cp1252')
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(data, 'sasfile.csv')
Perhaps try this and let me know how long it takes to produce?

Comment: I do not need to actually output the SAS table to a csv. My roundabout solution is to create a csv from SAS and read that csv into memory via Python in order to work with it. I think calling pd.read_sas() without chunking will cause it to take even longer though (permitted I don't hit some kind of overflow error).

edit: I think I see what you meant here - create a SAS7BDATReaer object and output to csv then read in the csv in the next line. I'm hitting an AttributeError but I will try to play with this.

Comment: I understand you don't need the CSV, however possibly creating the file in CSV via Python rather than loading the entire SAS file into a list may be beneficial. Then once in a CSV format you can load it into Python and do as you wish... Either that or you can schedule the export of the SAS dataset in SAS and load the exported CSV from a file (I amn't sure how your system is configured). Or load the SAS Dataset into a database and work from there...

Comment: This package may also be benefical
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sas7bdat

Comment: Why would csv export/import not work? You do same but with a SAS dataset? Just have SAS run a `proc export`. What script would be automated? You can even have SAS run an X command line call passing the csv file as argument to Python script.

Comment: My hope is to stay out of SAS completely (as a company we are transitioning out of it) so I'd like to keep this script exclusively Python - I was mainly curious why pd.read_csv() was so much faster than chunking the SAS table and reading it in with pd.read_sas()

Comment: @JackNicholson - yes I've seen that package - its documentation is abysmal for one even though it lets you execute SAS code within a Python script - but per my above comment I am trying to stay out of SAS completely. Eventually this table will be moved to a new platform and I'd like to just be able to edit this current script to find the table in its new location rather than have to adjust the process once we aren't using SAS anymore.

Comment: Not surprising that reading CSV file would be faster. No need to transform floating point values to integer values (or potentially transform IBM floating point to IEEE floating point). Plus more development support in optimizing the code since does not require reverse engineering a proprietary data format.  But you will potentially lose a lot of metadata about your variables as there is no place to store that in a CSV file.  For example are you sure that when you read the CSV file you haven't inappropriately transformed some character strings that look like numbers into numeric values?

Comment: When I import the csv version I haven't had any issues in any of the analysis I'm doing (admittedly I am no expert in any of this and I'm still a novice Data Scientist). Your points make a lot of sense to me though - I hadn't thought about the metadata present in the .sas7bdat format that is being pulled in. This discussion is making me think that I just need to suck it up and output a csv regularly or accept the 45 minute load time (monthly script - so perhaps this isn't a big deal right now).

Comment: You can also lose some precision on your numeric values in the process of converting floating point to character strings and back again.

Comment: All numerics are integers in this case - but I understand the loss of precision with floating point conversions

Comment: I am seeing memory leaks on the Pandas read_sas function.. Is anybody else?